# SQL Server error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why does this query:

```
INSERT INTO [IN4MATICSystem_Pie].[dbo].[ArchivioErogazioni] 
   SELECT 
       IDTER, CODTER, IDTEV, CODTEV,  IDVEI, CODVEI, IDTEA, CODTEA, IDAUT, CODAUT,  
       IDGRV, CODGRV, IDGRA, CODGRA, IDERO, CODERO, IDPRO, CODPRO, DATA_EROG, 
       ORA_EROG, KMATTUALI, VOLUME_LT, IMPORTO, PRUNIT, INFO, MODIFICATO,  
       ANOMALA, ACCETTATA, ESPORTATO, IMPORTATO, IMPORTRIF, USER_INS, DATA_INS, 
       USER_MOD, DATA_MOD, TRAN_ID, TEMPERATURA, KG, VOLUME_COMPENSATO, ORE 
   FROM 
       [IS-SERVER_SQL\SVILUPPO].IN4MATICSystem_ARC.dbo.ArchivioErogazioni 
   WHERE 
       DATA_EROG >= CONVERT(datetime,'30/11/2014 00:00:00',103) 
       AND DATA_EROG <= CONVERT(datetime,'01/01/2015 23:59:59',103)
```

throw this error:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

This query doesn't throw anything:

```
 SELECT IDTER, CODTER, IDTEV, CODTEV,  IDVEI, CODVEI, IDTEA, CODTEA, IDAUT, CODAUT,  IDGRV, CODGRV, IDGRA, CODGRA, IDERO, CODERO,
 IDPRO, CODPRO, DATA_EROG, ORA_EROG, KMATTUALI, VOLUME_LT, IMPORTO, PRUNIT, INFO, MODIFICATO,  ANOMALA, ACCETTATA, ESPORTATO, IMPORTATO, 
 IMPORTRIF, USER_INS, DATA_INS, USER_MOD,  DATA_MOD, TRAN_ID, TEMPERATURA, KG, VOLUME_COMPENSATO,  ORE 
FROM [IS-SERVER_SQL\SVILUPPO].IN4MATICSystem_ARC.dbo.ArchivioErogazioni WHERE DATA_EROG >= CONVERT(datetime,'30/11/2014 00:00:00',103) AND DATA_EROG <= CONVERT(datetime,'01/01/2015 23:59:59',103)
```

Why?

Comment: Can it be the order in the insert?

Comment: The error says why you can't insert it...

Comment: Error says that no. of column's in `[IN4MATICSystem_Pie].[dbo].[ArchivioErogazioni]` table not match with the no. of column in `select statement`. Make sure select covers all the column in the `[IN4MATICSystem_Pie].[dbo].[ArchivioErogazioni]` or use column list in insert

Comment: You should **always** explicitly name and define **what columns** to insert into - in that case, you'd probably easily see that you either specify **too few** or **too many** columns with your `SELECT` than what the target table actually has .....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is clearly said by exception - that columns number or order of values selected doesn't match columns defined in ArchivioErogazioni.

It is almost always better to insert using explicit list of columns to insert to. This can prevent you from many "logical" errors too.

For example, let's assume table

```
dbo.SomeTable(Name_First nvarchar(20), Name_Last nvarchar(20))
```

Let's assume you just forget that column order in `SomeTable` is `Name_First` than `Name_Last` and you're inserting like

```
insert into dbo.SomeTable
select Name_Last, Name_First
from Some_Other_Table_Or_Subquery
```

In this case you will get no errors - but obviously you will insert wrong values (swapped names).

Consider this approach:

```
insert into dbo.SomeTable (Name_Last, Name_First)
select Name_Last, Name_First
from Some_Other_Table_Or_Subquery
```

In this case you don't need to remember columns order in the table you're inserting - as you explicitly specified columns you're inserting and order - so previous logical error is unlikely to happen in this case.

It's a little bit "silly" example, but I hope it makes sense.